# Other players deploying glider later than mine in Fortnite BR?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

#### Problem:

In ***Fortnite Battle Royale***, after I deploy from the battle bus, I dive throughout the air until I automatically deploy the glider. However, I see some other players that are lower than me, meaning that somehow they deployed their glider later than mine.

#### Question:

My question, is how are they lower than me in the air *(Sinse they deployed their glider later)*?

How can I be as low as they are?

Is this random or is this the same automatic deploy time for all?

---

*I hope this question makes sense.*

Comment: It depends on the height above the terrain meaning you will deploy sooner if you are over or near a mountain, or later if you  over flat, lower ground. Though there are times when I see players deploy very close to my position yet significantly lower.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill Thats what im asking about. Pepole that are really close to my postion (ex. teammates) deploy later and they can reach houses sooner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objects in the terrain and the height of the terrain can affect your glider deployment height. If you dive-bomb above a tree you will deploy earlier because of the tree. Same goes for houses, mountains, cars, rocks. You want avoid these. A general rule of thumb is to avoid dropping on objects and aim for the lowest part of the ground.

Also, you kind of have to build up the game sense to when, where, and how high you should be to land at a specific place. Some good practice is to have a couple designated landing towns and chose a specific building you will always aim for when landing there. You will have done it correctly if you are the first one down

Answer (score 3):

In addition to terrain height below you as @SPYBUG96 noted, the other player may have simply deployed sooner than you and glided at a more optimal horizontal or vertical angle. The steeper you glide, the faster you get lower and are able to deploy your glider. If your goal location is far away from the bus route there will an ideal time to jump at the best angle.